# Pandas: Partial dependence plots + One hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am currently working through [this tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/partial-dependence-plots). What I am currently trying to display is how 'survival' was influenced by gender (Sex in the dataset). As that is categorial data I must first transform that data. I tried it with  one hot encoding, but that doesn't seem to be the right approach. Anyone who can help me with that?

```
titanic_data = pd.read_csv('../input/titanic/train.csv')
titanic_y = titanic_data.Survived
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier()

titanic_sex = titanic_data.Sex
one_hot_encoded_training_predictors = pd.get_dummies(titanic_sex)

titanic_X_colns = ['PassengerId','Age', 'Fare', one_hot_encoded_training_predictors]
titanic_X = titanic_data[titanic_X_colns]
my_imputer = Imputer()
imputed_titanic_X = my_imputer.fit_transform(titanic_X)

clf.fit(imputed_titanic_X, titanic_y)
titanic_plots = plot_partial_dependence(clf, features=[1,2,3], X=imputed_titanic_X, 
                                        feature_names=titanic_X_colns, grid_resolution=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

[PDPbox](https://github.com/SauceCat/PDPbox) handles partial dependence plots for categorical variables encoded as OHE (Although it seems it's not actively maintained)